# Using wget from a Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, wget

I have a question about `wget` in python.
When I make a `wget` in my command line I get a file, but when I use `wget` function in python I get a 403 forbidden error.

```
sudo wget -O /home/dirk/values.json https://api.bitladon.com/markets/
```

This gives me a file called `values.json.`

```
--2021-03-01 09:30:59--  https://api.bitladon.com/markets/
Resolving api.bitladon.com (api.bitladon.com)... 2606:4700::6812:1c7a, 
2606:4700::6812:1d7a, 104.18.28.122, ...
Connecting to api.bitladon.com 
(api.bitladon.com)|2606:4700::6812:1c7a|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/json]
Saving to: ‘values.json’

/home/dirk/values.json             [ <=>    ]  67.57K  --.-KB/s    in 0.004s

2021-03-01 09:30:59 (17.5 MB/s) - ‘/home/dirk/values.json’ saved [69190]
```

My code in python

```
import wget

url = 'https://api.bitladon.com/markets/'
print(url)
wget.download(url, '/home/dirk/values.json')
```

However in python I get an error.

```
https://api.bitladon.com/markets/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "trading.py", line 20, in <module>
wget.download(url, '/home/dirk/values.json')
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/wget.py", line 316, in download
(tmpfile, headers) = ThrowOnErrorOpener().retrieve(url, tmpfile, callback)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1824, in retrieve
fp = self.open(url, data)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1790, in open
return getattr(self, name)(url)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1999, in open_https
return self._open_generic_http(self._https_connection, url, data)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1962, in _open_generic_http
return self.http_error(
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1984, in http_error
return self.http_error_default(url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/wget.py", line 287, in http_error_default
raise Exception("{0}: {1}".format(errcode, errmsg))
Exception: 403: Forbidden
```

Could someone explain me what the difference is and how I can solve it?

Comment: `wget` is not a native Python command, so there must be more to you script that what's shown in your question. Please provide a complete [mre].

Comment: Besides, I tried your command "wget -O /home/dirk/values.json https://api.bitladon.com/markets/". This get 403 Forbidden on my machine.

Comment: use it natively, run the command using `os.system()`

Comment: @neilharia7 there is a `wget` library for python, no need to shell out https://pypi.org/project/wget/

Comment: just a workaround, why add an unnecessary dependency if you just want to download files.

Comment: Also, if your need the json for your Python program, you can use the `requests` library to load it, which is much easier to do in Python.

Comment: But this URI is returning 403 always. Even if called directly. Do you pass any headers or token for access?

Comment: @Ritwik G No, if I open the url in a browser you will get the data as one big data file based on json. If I put sudo wget -O /home/dirk/values.json https://api.bitladon.com/markets in my ubuntu command line I get a files called values.json with the same contents as in the browser. Only with wget in python I get a 403 forbidden.

Comment: @neilharia7 How does os.system() work in my code?

Comment: Weird, I'm getting error 1020 access denied while opening it on the browser, anyway, @dirk verbeek the command that you're actually typing on your terminal will be written inside os.system() like `os.system('wget -O ... ')` though you can use fstrings to pass the arguments inside it

Comment: @neilharia7 thanks os.system works perfect. Thanks a lot.

Comment: happy to help!.